# python size of byte string in bytes

Tags: python, byte

I'm confused as to why:

```py
len(b'123') == 3
import sys
sys.getsizeof(b'123') == 36
```

What exactly is `b'123'`?

Comment: It's an immutable sequence of (3) bytes, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe has stated, `b'123'` is an immutable sequence of bytes, in this case of 3 bytes. Your confusion appears to be because `len()` and `sys.getsizeof(b'123')` are not the same thing.

`len()` queries for the number of items contained in a container. For a string that's the number of characters, in your case you have 3 bytes, so its length will be 3.

> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (string, tuple or list) or a mapping (dictionary).

`sys.getsizeof()` on the other hand returns the memory size of the **object**, this means you are not only getting the size of the *bytes*, as it a full object it also has its methods, attributes, addresses... which are all considered in that size.

> Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation specific.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `b` before `123`, indicates that the literal should become a bytes literal, rather than a string literal.

`str` literals = a sequence of Unicode characters (Latin-1, UCS-2 or UCS-4, [depending on the widest character in the string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/))

`bytes` literals = a sequence of octets (integers between 0 and 255)

Put simply - you use `str` for text, and `bytes` for low level binary data.